# Windows Azure Cache Perverting Value

Tags: windows, caching, azure, appfabric

I've setup my Windows Azure project to use my App Fabric Cache.  However when I initialize (Put) a value into the cache and read it back it is either null or 0 in some cases.  Why is this?

I am looping through a resultset and storing each entity with its unique key like so:

```
foreach (VideoEntity v in results)
{
    videos.Add(v);
    videoIDs.Add(v.RowKey);

    // save the video to cache
    cache.Put(v.RowKey, v, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
}
```

and here is the code to read it back:

```
Func<object, VideoEntity> GetVideoEntity_action = (object obj) =>
{
    DataCache tCache = factory.GetDefaultCache();
    VideoEntity tempVideo = (VideoEntity)tCache.Get((string)obj);
    return tempVideo;
};
```

When I read what went in to what came out in particular the "sortIndex" property has changed.  I'm presuming it's a bug in my code, but went as far as I could to where it finally calls the caching service and can only conclude that the caching service is perverting the value somehow ?

Anyone else having problems with the caching service, mangling values?

I am using c# MVC3 (ASP.Net 4.0, Windows Azure SDK November 2011 release), Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

Comment: Are you employing versioning during writes? Are you facing threadsafety issues? How long after caching are you retrieving? (Data may not be "immediately" available after put/add action.) Is obj really your key?

Comment: no im not doing versioning, im just looping around and storing the enitity into the cache.  im getting it straight away, and sometimes seconds or minutes later.  Is there any tools to check whats in the cache, like loop through the cache and output the contents? or an explorer so i can see whats really in there ...

Comment: I'm not aware of any tools for examining the contents of a cache.  I would be interested in seeing one though.

Answer (score 0):

AppFabric Caching seems to use WCF for serialization, which means that it respects the various serialization attributes. In particular, if you have the `[IgnoreDataMember]` attribute on a property, then that field won't be cached. When you the object back out, the field will have the default value for that type.

If that is your problem, you can work around it by serializing my objects to byte[] using a BinaryFormatter before caching them.

### Example

Just to verify that the [IgnoreDataMember] attribute will cause the problem I mentioned, here's some sample code.

```
public class TestClass
{
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class TestContract
{
    [IgnoreDataMember]
    public int MyInt { get; set; }
}

public void DataMemberIgnoreTest()
{
    //elided creation of the DataCacheFactory here

    DataCache cache = factory.GetDefaultCache();

    TestClass t1 = new TestClass();
    t1.MyInt = 25;

    TestContract t2 = new TestContract();
    t2.MyInt = 25;

    cache.Put("t1", t1);
    cache.Put("t2", t2);

    TestClass retrievedT1 = cache.Get("t1") as TestClass;
    TestContract retrievedT2 = cache.Get("t2") as TestContract;

    Console.Out.WriteLine("t1 value: " + retrievedT1.MyInt); //25
    Console.Out.WriteLine("t2 value: " + retrievedT2.MyInt); //0
}
```

While I can't say for sure that this is your problem, it's a definite possibility.

Comment: I've followed several tutorials and I am presuming its correct.  Obviously there is something wrong with it though.  So I've just reverted to removing app fab cache until it becomes clear what the problem is.  Does anyone have any clear examples how to put and get etc?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Most of the ways to call the cache incorrectly would result in you getting back no object at all from cache. The other possibility is that your code is changing the values. eg, another thread/request/whatever is setting a different value to the cache.